# Failing do the scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm having a problem when I try to scrape the lyrics from google. I just want to extract the lyrics but instead is giving me the all text

I tried

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=RaindropsKeepFallinonMyHead+lyrcis&')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser').find_all('div',jsname="WbKHeb")
print(soup)
```

and this:

```
def extract(Title):
    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
    url= f'https://www.google.com/search?q={Title}lyrics'
    r= requests.get(url, headers) # starting to get data from bilboard website
    soup= BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser') # pull html from the website
    return soup
def transform(soup):
    page = soup.find('div',class_="B03h3d V14nKc EN1f2d ptcLIOszQJu__wholepage-card wp-ms")
    pageTEXT=BeautifulSoup(page.prettify(), 'html.parser').get_text()
    return print(page)
    
c=extract('RaindropsKeepFallinonMyHead')
print(c)
```

Comment: In the second version, just use `page.get_text()`

Comment: You never call `transform()`

Answer (score 2):

> ```py
> r= requests.get(url, headers)
> ```

You need to use `headers=headers` because if it's not specified, the second [argument](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.request) is `params`.

---

> ```py
> page = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=RaindropsKeepFallinonMyHead+lyrcis&')
> soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser').find_all('div',jsname="WbKHeb") 
> print(soup)
> ```

I just get `[]` with this. (Maybe `jsname="WbKHeb"` is only in the html for specific devices?)

With your second method, I just get `None`....

---

You can try **`.select('div:has(>span:has(>span):has(~span>span))~div div')`** instead of *`.find_all('div',jsname="WbKHeb")`*.

<sub>**(In case you're not familiar with it, [`.select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) uses [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php) to find element tags.)**</sub>

```py
title = 'Raindrops Keep Fallin on My Head'
url = f'https://www.google.com/search?q={title.replace(" ", "+")}+lyrics'
r = requests.get(url)
print('[', r.status_code, r.reason, 'from', r.url, f']\n{"-"*85}\n')
# r.raise_for_status()

lcSel = 'div:has(>span:has(>span):has(~span>span))~div div'
print(('\n\n'+'-'*80+'\n\n').join([el.get_text(' ').strip() + (
    f' ( {el.a.get("href")} )' if el.a else ''
) for el in [soup.select_one(s) for s in [
    f'{lcSel} span>div:has(a)', 
    f'{lcSel} span:has(>div a)+span', 
    f'{lcSel}:not(:has(span))'
]]]))
```

should print

```
[ 200 OK from https://www.google.com/search?q=Raindrops+Keep+Fallin+on+My+Head+lyrics ]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Source:  LyricFind ( https://lyrics.lyricfind.com/ )

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Songwriters: Burt F. Bacharach /  Hal David
Raindrops Keep Fallin' on My Head lyrics © BMG Rights Management, Royalty Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Raindrops are falling on my head
And just like the guy whose feet are too big for his bed
Nothing seems to fit
Those raindrops are falling on my head, they keep falling

So I just did me some talking to the sun
And I said I didn't like the way he got things done
Sleeping on the job Raindrops are falling on my head
And just like the guy whose feet are too big for his bed
Nothing seems to fit
Those raindrops are falling on my head, they keep falling

So I just did me some talking to the sun
And I said I didn't like the way he got things done
Sleeping on the job
Those raindrops are falling on my head, they keep falling

But there's one thing I know
The blues they send to meet me
Won't defeat me, it won't be long
Till happiness steps up to greet me

Raindrops keep falling on my head
But that doesn't mean my eyes will soon be turning red
Crying's not for me
'Cause I'm never gonna stop the rain by complaining
Because I'm free
Nothing's worrying me

It won't be long till happiness steps up to greet me

Raindrops keep falling on my head
But that doesn't mean my eyes will soon be turning red
Crying's not for me
'Cause I'm never gonna stop the rain by complaining
Because I'm free
Nothing's worrying me
```